# Hand Number Recog

Tags: python, tensorflow, model

Why am I only getting 67% accuracy here?

I even used text to create the numbers, which should have made it easier.

It says the model has 97% accuracy.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_train, axis=1)
x_test = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_test, axis=1)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=256, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=256, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=10, activation=tf.nn.softmax))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train,epochs=10)

loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
model.save('number_model')

for x in range(1,10):
    img = cv.imread(f'{x}.png')[:,:,0]
    img = np.invert(np.array([img]))
    prediction = model.predict(img)
    print(f'guess: {np.argmax(prediction)}')
    plt.imshow(img[0], cmap=plt.cm.binary)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Who says that the model has 97% accuracy? Why do you think that you have 67%?

Comment: What does "Hand Number Recog" mean?

Comment: What does "use text to create the numbers" mean? As opposed to what? Which text? Which numbers?

Comment: The 97% accuracy is when hand-written numbers from the large database, mnist, are then tested with another part of the mnist database. The algorithm is to recognize hand-written numbers via the created model. Instead of writing the numbers tpo see if they can be recognized, I then used ones done in Photoshop with their text option. So, it should be easier to read those versus the hand-written ones..